# Insert date value yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to insert some records with date values. The format is `'2006-07-26 00:00:00.000'.` When I try the query I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

How do I format that to get it inserted?

```
INSERT [dbo].[NAMES] (
    [NAME_CODE]
    ,[NAME_ID]
    ,[NAME_CODE_ID]
    ,[PREVIOUS_ID]
    ,[GOVERNMENT_ID]
    ,[PREV_GOV_ID]
    ,[PREFIX]
    ,[FIRST_NAME]
    ,[MIDDLE_NAME]
    ,[LAST_NAME]
    ,[SUFFIX]
    ,[NICKNAME]
    ,[PREFERRED_ADD]
    ,[BIRTH_DATE]
    ,[BIRTH_CITY]
    ,[BIRTH_STATE]
    ,[BIRTH_ZIP_CODE]
    ,[BIRTH_COUNTRY]
    ,[BIRTH_COUNTY]
    ,[DECEASED_DATE]
    ,[DECEASED_FLAG]
    ,[RELEASE_INFO]
    ,[CREATE_DATE]
    ,[CREATE_TIME]
    ,[CREATE_OPID]
    ,[CREATE_TERMINAL]
    ,[REVISION_DATE]
    ,[REVISION_TIME]
    ,[REVISION_OPID]
    ,[REVISION_TERMINAL]
    ,[ABT_JOIN]
    ,[TAX_ID]
    ,[PersonId]
    ,[PrimaryPhoneId]
    ,[Last_Name_Prefix]
    ,[LegalName]
    )
VALUES (
    N'P'
    ,2
    ,N'P000000002'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,363768306
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'Dr.'
    ,N'Pever'
    ,N'G'
    ,N'Giper'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'PERM'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'N'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'2006-07-26 00:00:00.000'
    ,N'1900-01-01 08:39:02.000'
    ,N'SCT'
    ,1
    ,N'2014-06-27 00:00:00.000'
    ,N'1900-01-01 15:39:44.617'
    ,N'SSTULTS'
    ,1
    ,N'*'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,1
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'NULL'
    ,N'NULL'
    ) GO
```

Comment: I am guessing that you want to insert NULL to some columns but you are trying to insert the string literal "NULL" which cannot be converted to a datetime. And you only need the leading N when dealing with nvarchar data. Make your NULLs actuall NULL and the problem will probably go away.

Comment: What is the data type of the columns Create_Date, Create_Time, Revision_Date, and Revision_Time. Also, is the Birth_Date field nullable?

Comment: the types are datetime, i changed to actual nulls and it inserted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `BIRTH_DATE` and `DECEASED_DATE` are date fields, then those will fail because you're assigning the string `NULL` instead of a null value (well, not technically a null value, but you know what I mean). The other `NULL` strings are a really bad idea as well - if you want null, then use it, not a string with the value of `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not. This is especially true when trying to convert string literals into date values.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start **phasing out** the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible